# how to fix type mismatch error in this specific function?

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

The code is working for 3 times in Excel VBA but at the forth time it gives an error. When I put a toggle point there, the code cannot pass "Duration = Duration + drtn" and "Type MisMatch" error shows up. Is there any way to fix the code?

```
Function simul(t)

Dim wk As Worksheet
Set wk = Worksheets("Simulation")
Dim FoundCell As Range
Duration = 0
i = 1
char = "StartStep"
drtn = 0

While i = 1
m = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A30"), char)

Set FoundCell = wk.Range("A:A").Find(char)

x = FoundCell.Row
y = FoundCell.Row

Dim myarray() As Variant
ReDim myarray(m)

For j = 0 To m - 1
myarray(j) = wk.Range("E" & x)
x = x + 1
Next
    
If char = "A" Then
    drtn = Application.Evaluate("LOGNORM.INV(RAND(),r5,r6)")
ElseIf char = "B" Then
    drtn = Application.Evaluate("ABS(NtLogisticInv(RAND(),r29,r30)")
ElseIf char = "C" Then
    drtn = Application.Evaluate("r17*(-LN(1-RAND()))^(1/r18)")
Else
    i = 0
    drtn = 0
End If

Duration = Duration + drtn

r = Rnd()
k = 0
While r > myarray(k)
    k = k + 1
Wend
char = wk.Range("B" & y + k)

Wend

wk.Range("U" & t) = Duration

End Function
```

Comment: The procedure doesn't return anything, so it's not a function, but a sub. If you use `Option Explicit` at the top of your module (before all procedures), you will have to declare all variables but it will probably be easier to find out what's wrong with the code.

Comment: What's the value of `drtn` when it fails?

Comment: Under which condition may drtn fail?